# load an html file in _.template

Tags: jquery, ajax, underscore.js

I am trying to use underscore.template to compiles a JavaScript templates by loading an html through  `jQuery.get` in this way:

```
_.template($.get('my_template.html'), $get(function(data) { 
    return data;
}));
```

but I get the following message

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace'
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

[`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) doesn't work the way you think it does. `$.get('my_template.html')` doesn't return `my_template.html`, it returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), the thing you're GETting is passed to the `$.get` callback:

```
$.get('my_template.html', function(html) {
    // my_template.html will be in `html` here.
});
```

So if you really want to use `$.get` to retrieve your template, you're going to have to wait for the AJAX call to return something from the server and that won't happen until later. You could make a synchronous AJAX request using the `async` option to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **async** (default: `true`)
>   Type: Boolean
>   By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to `true` by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. [...] Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

That would look like this:

```
var tmpl;
$.ajax({
    url: 'my_template.html',
    type: 'get',
    async: false,
    success: function(html) {
        tmpl = html;
    }
});
var t = _.template(tmpl);
// `t` is now your compiled template function
```

I don't recommend this though, `async:false` is a nasty thing to do to your users and using it will make people think your application has locked up or crashed.

I would find a different way to load your templates. Throw them all in `<script>` elements so they're always available or deliver them along with whatever JavaScript is going to use them.